# Perl on Windows or Linux

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl,I want to do a project assigned to me in Perl.
 Should I use Perl in Windows or Linux?
 I am not able to conclude the significant advantages or disadvantages of Perl on a particular             OS.

Comment: Since you're fresh, pick one which you're more familiar with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl is ridiculously portable.  By and large, the ports act pretty similar on different machines.  For the most part, you won't notice a difference between running on Windows and running on Linux (or BSD, or Mac OS X, or any number of older platforms:  Plan 9, Amiga, VAX, Mac OS Classic, etc.).

That is, for the most part.  There are [a few weird things that will bite you occasionally](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html) (especially the Platforms and Function Implementation sections).  Given a choice, I would pick Perl on Linux.  That's partly because I like Linux more than Windows, partly because many of Perl's core modules and functions are inspired by POSIX, and partly because many of the core developers use Linux (the perlport document is written largely as "this is what you'll see different if you run on something other than UNIX.").

Answer (score 1):

There are some modules which are better supported under Linux than Windows, but the vast majority work well in both.  In particular, the [DWIMperl](http://dwimperl.com/) distribution for Windows is amazing. It's based on [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) which includes the Padre IDE, a modern version of Perl, database drivers, `Moose`, most of `Task::Kensho`, `Dancer`, and many, many other commonly used modules, along with tools such as `cpanm` and a C compiler, so installing new modules is a breeze. Given that modern Perl development involves lots of CPAN modules, it's great to have a batteries-included distribution.

So really, I'd suggest using whatever operating system you're most comfortable with. The days when Perl was much better supported under Linux compared to Windows are mostly behind us.

Answer (score 0):

I said to go for Linux OS only because in all Linux machine are have pre-installed Perl modules.So better to Linux machine only.